# Uploading images using rn-fetch-blob times out very often

Tags: react-native

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob to upload images to a rest api. Im racing the promise against a 10 second timeout and im getting a lot of timeouts in production. We are uploading very small images. The app is not even reaching the server when the timeout promise rejects. Im just curious if there is anything i can do with this. Everything seems to work great with consistent network (in other words at my desk haha) but i know sometimes mobile devices try to run on wifi even though there isn't internet access over wifi (personal experience). Any advice is appreciated. Code sample:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
'PUT',
`${API_HOST}${path}`,
{
'Content-Type': `image/${fileType}`,
Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
},
RNFetchBlob.wrap(file)
)
```

Comment: You could try to implement an `offline-first` approach by keeping an app state locally in the local storage and if the request to the server times out, then try it again later automatically. This might be complicated if the app has more sophisticated functionality. You could at least catch the error and tell the user to try later in form of a toast or whatever.

Comment: @DavidScholz my app uses redux saga and sqlite to do all that. It has full offline capability, I was just trying to see why this happens so often.. my first instinct is that it shouldn't considering how powerful our networks are these days.